# How do I properly subscribe to a topic using eclipse?

Tags: iot, publish-subscribe, paho, alibaba-cloud

I am working on IOT application wherein I will be connecting a mobile application to a pub sub broker to release portable chargers from a powerbank box. I have documentation from the manufacture of the boxes but I can't seem to establish two way communication between my computer and the box. I am using THE PAHO-eclipse client to debug the connection but I keep getting a subscription failed message when trying to send the subscriptions that they suggest in the documentation. Does anyone see anything inherently wrong with what I am trying? is there a better approach that I am overlooking to troubleshoot subscriptions?

[Here is what my eclipse client looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMet4.png)

[Here is the call I make to get specific information on each powerbank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sM3oL.png)

[here is a segment of the documentation where it says to subscribe in the format that I have in eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ovCA.png)

I am new to using PubSub so any suggestions or pointers would be super appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: From where did you get the the documentation link? It seems incorrect to me.

Answer (score 0):

The third link that you have shared, that is of documentation, shows the **topic** as:

```
/$productKey/$deviceName/user/get
```

Where as, I think following is the documentation link:
https://d.test.dudubox.cn/sw/web/docs/aliyuniot.html

English translated version:
https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=zh-CN&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fd.test.dudubox.cn%2Fsw%2Fweb%2Fdocs%2Faliyuniot.html

which shows the **topic** as:

```
/$productKey/$deviceName/get
```

Also have a look at the following source link:
https://cloudcpu.blogspot.com/2020/01/alibaba-cloud-iot-platform-with-mqtt.html

I hope this helps!